# Double dot product in Cylindrical polar coordinates - Strain Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus, coordinate-systems, elasticity, stress-strain

I'm working with a problem in linear elasticity, and I have to calculate the strain energy function as follows:

$$2W=σ_{ij}ε_{ij}$$

Where σ and ε are symmetric rank 2 tensors.

For cartesian coordinates it is really easy because the metric is just the identity matrix, hence:
$$
2W=σ_{xx}ε_{xx}+σ_{yy}ε_{yy}+σ_{zz}ε_{zz}+2σ_{xy}ε_{xy}+2σ_{xz}ε_{xz}+2σ_{yz}ε_{yz}
$$
My question is how the expression should be for cylindrical polar coordinates $(r,θ,z)$

Comment: Well, with the metric in polar coordinates, of course! Since you seem to be aware of how the metric works, I don't see your problem. (Also: One of the index pairs in your opening equation should be upstairs, shouldn't it?)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my problem, I don't know how to use the cylindrical metric for rank two tensors. In GR I mainly used the metric to rise and lower indices of vectors or dual vectors. I don't know why I'm struggling with rank 2... Any way, I have to express the equation component by component. Thanks!

Comment: Look carefully at the definitions of the stress and strain tensors in Cartesian coordinates. Try to make these definitions coordinate independent (e.g. send partial derivatives to covariant derivatives). Then do the proper contractions to build a scalar from them.

Comment: This is a cross-post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883652/double-dot-product-in-cylindrical-polar-coordinates-strain-energy

Comment: Answered on MATH.SE